# how to process data for buliding ASR using keras and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, speech-recognition

I am new to machine learning. I am making a basic ASR system for my local language  , can anyone please guide me how can i process audio and text data.
i have seven sentences of variable length , each sentence has multiple wav files.
i am using keras and tensorflow backend.

thank you very much.

Comment: You'd better take existing package and adapt it to your needs. Consider facebook wav2letter or https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/DeepSpeech

Comment: thank you very much for replying but i am making ASR for my local language and that is not going good  with deepspech that is why wanna make from scratch

Comment: If you unable to fix deepspeech issues, you won't be able to set things from scratch. You'd better ask about specific deepspeech trouble.

Comment: You could look at Mozilla's implementation of DeepSpeech to get ideas for loading data for ASR. https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech